# My VBA code is not working, error message "Compile error: Invalid outside procedure"

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a list of data compiled for the year 2019. And I want to eliminate INACTIVE lines in my excel data and move them to a separate worksheet titled "Inactive(12mths)". I placed my activity column as A where I will list "Inactive" or leave blank.

I copied the code over on a new excel sheet and tried to save it, but when I alt-F8, I can't see the saved vba code too and it doesn't run.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
' Only react to edits in Column A:  '
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sheets("Buyer Limit").Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    ' Dont do anything if > 1 cell was just changed:   '
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ' Only make the change if the new value in Col A is "inactive":    '            If Target.Value = "Inactive" Then
            ' Find the next available cell on the Inactive(12mths) sheet for a name:   '
            Dim nextRange As Range
            Set nextRange = Sheets("Inactive(12mths").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            ' Cut the employee name and status and paste onto the Inactive(12mths) sheet:   '
            Range(Target, Target.Offset(0, -1)).Cut
            Sheets("Buyer Limit").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Inactive(12mths").Range(nextRange.Address)
        End If
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

I expect the output of this vba code to run automatically when I open the worksheet but it doesn't automate itself. I am not sure if I had saved it wrongly. =(

25Jun19 (Update)

I have rewrote the quote, but I still can't get it to work on my excel sheet, Macro-enabled...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
    ' Only react to edits in Column A:  '
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sheets("Buyer").Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Dont do anything if > 1 cell was just changed:   '
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            ' Only make the change if the new value in Col A is "Inactive":    '
            If Target.Value = "Inactive" Then
                ' Find the next available cell on the Inactive sheet for a name:   '
                Dim nextRange As Range
                Set nextRange = Sheets("Inactive").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                ' Cut the CP name and status and paste onto the Inactive sheet:   '
                Range(Target, Target.Offset(0, -1)).Cut
                Sheets("Buyer").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Inactive").Range(nextRange.Address)
        End If
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` for this to work automatically, whenever you change the Worksheet. If you want to run it whenever you open the Workbook you need to use `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` in Thisworkbok

Comment: @Mikku I don't think the OP would use `Private Sub Worksheet_Change` event handler but rather `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate` as this will run when the user selects and activates the sheet (ie. opening it).

Comment: @Dean .. even the use of that is possible.. Actually it wasn't clear in the question. Anyways, that's right too :)

Comment: That error usually means you've got some text in a code block outside of the procedure (i.e. not between  `Sub` and  `End Sub`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything in your posted code which would account for "invalid outside procedure".  Do you have other code you've not posted?

Something like this should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Column = 1 and Target.Value = "Inactive" then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Resize(1, 2).Cut _
          Sheets("Inactive(12mths").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Is there a typo here `Sheets("Inactive(12mths")` ?

Comment: I edited the names are realising that it could have caused the complications